# Тире или двоеточие в расписании?

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно обозначать время работы?

Например:

*Дети 5-7 лет. Время занятий: 17.00-18.00*

Answer (score 2):

Между цифрами,

кроме кодов, маркировок или телефонных номеров (что уже не есть русский язык),

дефис не ставится,

только тире.

*Дети 5—7 лет. Время занятий: 17.00—18.00*

Тире от цифр не отделяется пробелами.

Двоеточие ставится факультативно, это скорее оформительский элемент.

Comment: Разве правильно писать "17.00", а не "17:00"?

Comment: Это опять же формальность, не имеющая отношения к языку.

Comment: Не имеющая отношения к языку? А к чему же тогда?

Comment: Оформление. Условность. Вопрос вкусового предпочтения. *В сплошном тексте и на вывесках время пишется через двоеточие, согласно п. 7.3 справочника Мильчина.

Магазин открыт с 10:30 до 23:00;
Здоровый сон: 12:00—08:00.*

Comment: Нашла поддержку Вашему мнению, чем и делюсь: *Международный стандарт обозначения времени – через двоеточие: 21:00* - http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=278248

Comment: Как Вы можете видеть, международные стандарты *оформления* не имеют отношения к языку.